# how to read current frame buffer in Windows Phone 7 or 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, framebuffer

Is there a method to read the frame buffer of the current screen in Windows Phone 7 or 8? I searched some data about the frame buffer.Does anyone know how to read the current frame buffer in detail?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you:

```
WriteableBitmap screenshot = new WriteableBitmap(LayoutRoot, null);
```